# Getting raw wcs-dem value with mapserver

Tags: mapserver, wcs, getcoverage

I retrieve wcs-dem.

```
curl --trace -i  -H "Content-Type: application/image" -XGET "http://127.0.1.1/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=wcs1.map&SERVICE=WCS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetCoverage&coverage=dem&CRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=35.670381,35.813051,44.81901235734796,42.106463&WIDTH=1600&HEIGHT=1066&FORMAT=GTiff" > dem.tif
```

But, it generates 3 bands without having any DEM value as:

(gdalinfo dem.tif)

```
Band 1 Block=1600x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=1600x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=1600x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
```

---

shp2img produces proper results:

```
Band 1 Block=2707x3 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
```

What am I doing possibly wrong?

What do I have to do to get raw wcs-dem value?

Comment: How have you defined the GTiff outputformat in your mapfile?

Comment: like this:OUTPUTFORMAT
    NAME "GEOTIFF_16"
    DRIVER "GDAL/GTiff"
    MIMETYPE "image/tiff"
    IMAGEMODE "INT16"
    EXTENSION "tif"
  END

Comment: What version of MapServer do you have? Does it support WCS version 2.0.0?